# PHP change string with name set from multiple strings

Tags: php

Ok, before I start I want to apologise for this question, it is so hard to write this and make sense, I spent 3 days looking for an answer.

I have an array made up of 12 items, all the days of the month called `months_array`

Later in the code I have a foreach loop set to run for every item in another array as `current_date`. The contents of the items in this array is `01` to `12` in order.

I will write some code that will do what I want, but not ideal:

```
if ($current_date == "01") {
    $January++;
}
```

I would than have one of them for each month, so 02 and Febuary ect.

What I want to do instead of this is have PHP figure out what month we are referring to, and treat is as the name of a string, eg: `[$moths_array[$current_date - 1]]++;`

That code doesn't work. So to explain a bit more, `months_array` has the month names in it. So `$months_array[0]` is equal to `January`. If `$current_date = 1` than `$months_array[$current_date - 1]` is also equal to January.

So I need it to than get that "January" or "Febuary" ect. and use that as the variable name. So what ever month it gets, add 1 to it. So than I can use `echo $january` or `echo $febuary`.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Code I have :

```
//Print Analytics
echo "<div class='project_page_analytics'>";
echo "<div class='project_page_analytics_title'>";
echo "<p>";
echo "Analytics";
echo "</p>";
echo "</div>";

//Echo the Structure
$sql = "SELECT * FROM analytics_data WHERE corrospond='$project_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //If project
    while($analytic = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $analytics_array_date_temp_one = explode(" ", $analytic["date"]);
        $date = $date . " " .$analytics_array_date_temp_one[1];
    }
    $analytic_array_date = explode(" ", $date);
    $current_date = "01";
    $months_array = array("January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    $previous_date = $analytic_array_date[0];
    $March = 0;
    foreach($analytic_array_date as &$current_date) {
        if ($previous_date == $current_date) {
            [$months_array[$current_date - 1]] + 1;
        }
    }
    echo $March;
}
```

Comment: You could rewrite the keys in the `months_array` if you have to have it like that? [`Here is an example`](https://eval.in/305561)

Comment: Just a quick tip @Darren, you can put the $i++ right in with the key, and it will return $i, and then increment it. If you want to do the opposite (Increment it, and then return $i) simply reverse the ++ around (++$i).

Comment: Jayden: Please post the code that you've come up with so far, so that we can figure out what is wrong, and improve upon it.

Comment: @Danbopes touche! Good spot. I thought I'd give him a quick example of how he could achieve something like that :)

Comment: Couldn't you just try something like this.... `echo date("F",strtotime("1970-".$monthnumber."-01"));` and just use a two-digit number for month? The way you're going about things is complicated. Try to learn more about the date and strtotime functions.

Comment: @darren I still dont understand, could you please give me another example? Code is up. It pulls the information from a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't touch on your code. I think this will address your problem.

```
<?php 
    $current_date = array("1","1","3","2");
    $months_array = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    foreach($months_array as $month){
        ${$month} = 0;
    }

    for($i=0;$i<count($current_date);++$i) {
        $date = $current_date[$i];
        ${$months_array[$date-1]}++;
    }

    echo $January;
    echo $February;
?>
```